# ObjectContext instance has been disposed using LINQ and cannot get a JSON result

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, linq

I would to make an ASP.NET MVC API with data from my database. To do this I use LINQ. I create my context and get all tariffs where `delete` is false.

```csharp
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult Index()
{
    List<Tariff> temp = new List<Tariff>();
    using (Context context = new Context())
    {
        temp = context.Tariff.Where(t => !t.Delete).ToList<Tariff>();
    }
    return Json(temp, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

When I debug, temp contains a List of `System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Tariff_...` instead of `MyNamespace.Models.Tariff`. When I continue it gives me this exception:

> The `ObjectContext` instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You probably have lazy loading enabled and the associated collections on type `Tariff` are being enumerated during serialization. As serialization occurs after the `Context` instance has been disposed the Exception is thrown

Comment: @Igor: how can I disable that?

Comment: `DbContext.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;`

Comment: or place the return statement inside the `using` scope. As long you do not return Task<T>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disbale the lazy loading for the DB context:

```
context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```

If you need to do it for this query. And if you want it globally in the application, then in your ObjectContext constructor:

```
public DbContext() : base("name=DbContext", "DbContext")
{
    this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    OnContextCreated();
}
```